# Issue mapping timestamp column in sybase through ibatis 2.3 to a POJO

Tags: spring, sybase, ibatis

I am using ibatis 2.3 and sybase 15.0.3 with spring 3 and jconn2-5.5

I tried to map a timestamp column [ varbinary (8)] with byte array in my POJO. I received the following error:

> JZ006: Caught IOException: java.io.IOException: JZ0SM: Unsupported SQL type 1111" after trying BINARY and byte[] for jdbcType and javaType respectively in the parametermap.

What would be the appropriate  jdbcType and javaType to map this field through ibatis parametermap to a POJO?

Answer (score 0):

For fixed length columns, use fixed length datatypes.  Use BINARY(8).

It works for mapping Sybase TIMESTAMP columns onto other client software (I do not have your exact set).